# Sinatra server not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm

I've been working on the Odin Project and am currently working on the Sinatra portion.  I have things working on my work computer, but just tried to get things going on my home computer and they aren't working.  I installed RVM 1.29.1, Ruby 2.3.3, and Sinatra 2.0.0, and am just trying the simple hi.rb example:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Then I run, as a login shell:

```
ruby hi.rb
```

On my work computer the server starts and I can use localhost/4567, but on my home computer I get a huge error:

```
...rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/sinatra-2.0.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1638:in `compile': uninitialized constant #<Class:Sinatra::Base>::Mustermann (NameError)
and then a lot more along the same lines...
```

I've researched a bunch, and it seems like the only thing people say to do is make sure you are requiring **sinatra** (which I am).  The only other thing I'm suspicious of is that there is a conflict between my versions of Ruby, RVM, and Sinatra.  I just don't know how to find out if that is the case.

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I uninstalled the 'mustermann' gem and then reinstalled it.  My error message shortened up, but now reads:

```
...'initialize': uninitialized constant Sinatra::Base::Tilt (NameError)
```

Comment: Try `gem uninstall mustermann` then `gem instlall mustermann` again.

Comment: When you install `sinatra` as a standalone gem, it will also install `mustermann` as a dependency. Have you done something funny, like cancel the installation partway through - so `mustermann` is not installed on your machine? Try running `gem query musterman` -- it should show `mustermann (1.0.0)`?

Comment: @TomLord Ok, so I did that and my error shortened up, but is still there.  Now it says 'initialize': uninitialized constant Sinatra::Base::Tilt (NameError)

Comment: @mutantkeyboard Any suggestions now?

Comment: Just do the same procedure for tilt

Comment: @mutantkeyboard I did, and it acted like it wasn't even a gem